# The Foreign Key Options, ON DELETE CASCADE not working?

Tags: mysql, database, cascade

I am trying to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` for a database I'm working on. Didn't seem to work so I tested it out on a simple example with no success.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
data VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE foo2 (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
data2 VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_foo2_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES foo(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO foo (data) VALUE ('hello'),('world'),('mysql');
INSERT INTO foo2 (data2) VALUE ('hello2'),('world2'),('mysql2');

SELECT * FROM foo;

+----+-------+
| id | data  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | hello |
|  2 | world |
|  3 | mysql |
+----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM foo2;

+----+--------+
| id | data2  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | hello2 |
|  2 | world2 |
|  3 | mysql2 |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

DELETE FROM foo WHERE id=2;

SELECT * FROM foo;
+----+-------+
| id | data  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | hello |
|  3 | mysql |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM foo2;

+----+--------+
| id | data2  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | hello2 |
|  2 | world2 |
|  3 | mysql2 |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. I looked at similar questions and answers on here and I did exactly what they said and it still didn't work. Most of them just said to change to `ENGINE=InnoDb`, but I tried it and no success.

There must be something I'm missing here, and it's probably very obvious.. Monday mornings.

If anyone can shed some light on this little noob problem of mine, I would greatly appreciate it!

Edit: removed the `auto_increment` from `id` in `foo2` as it did not belong there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first thing that pops to mind is to check the setting of the `foreign_key_checks` variable.  If that's set to 0 (FALSE), then foreign key constraints are NOT enforced.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks'
```

To enable foeign key constraints, set to the variable to 1

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

NOTE: this affects only the current session. New sessions inherit the GLOBAL setting.

---

Also, verify that your tables are actually using the InnoDB engine, and that the foreign keys are defined. Easiest way is to get the output from:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;
SHOW CREATE TABLE foo2;
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

This is something that we expect *NOT* to be broken in MySQL 5.1.61.

As a workaround, try defining the foreign key constraint as a separate ALTER TABLE statement.

```
ALTER TABLE foo2 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foo2_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES foo(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

Comment: I tried it out and it's showing me foreign_key_checks value is ON, so I guess that's not the problem? :S

Comment: Well, I tried SHOW CREATE TABLE foo2 and I don't see any foreign keys! But I defined it when I created my table, so what's the problem here?

Comment: @302Laya: foreign_key_checks `ON` is the same as `1`, means foreign key checks are enabled. So you're right, that wouldn't be the problem.   Given the DDL you've posted, we know there aren't any `ON DELETE` triggers defined on the table.

Comment: That answer seems to match the problem. The *foreign_key_checks* var is session dependent and you @302Laya may have had the var Off during your tests. Try the test again while specifically setting the var to On.

Comment: @302Laya: the absence of a foreign key definition would explain the behavior. I would have expected the `CREATE TABLE foo2` statement to throw an error if the foreign key had not been created.

Comment: @ring0 As far as I know it's been on the whole time. I set it to 1 just now to be 100% sure, and tested again. Still the same thing, my record is deleted from table1 but not from table2.

Comment: @spencer7593 What do you mean? I created it exactly the way you see it above. Unless I made some kind of mistake?

Comment: @302Laya Tested on my own 5.5 server and it works fine. Don't you have a trigger or something specific in the config that would explain that? What is your server version?

Comment: @302Laya: I've run the test case above on my test 5.5 server (`version 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log`), and the row is removed from `foo2` as expected. I can't explain the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @ring0 5.1 I guess that would explain it! I'm not sure how to go about updating it, but I'll figure it out. I'm doing this for work and they just kind of threw me in the deep end with this one, learned it all from scratch in a couple of weeks. Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: @spencer7593 Server version: 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 (Ubuntu) there's the explanation. Thanks for your help too! :)

Comment: @spencer7593 As I said this is all new to me so I wouldn't really know but I'll take your word on that, Thanks again!

Comment: @spencer7593 I don't believe it but your workaround seems to have done the trick! How strange

Comment: @302Laya: It appears you may have discovered a bug in MySQL; and you have a workaround. (Before we jump the gun and declare it a bug though, we'd really need to examine the documentation for MySQL 5.1, and see if this is documented behavior. I suspect that this behavior  would not occur when the foreign key constraint is defined on another column, which is not an AUTO_INCREMENT or not a UNIQUE KEY column in the table. (I suspect that when the foreign key constraint is processed, MySQL attempts to create an index, but a matching index has already been created. That's just a suspicion.)

Comment: You could be right, who knows? In the meantime the workaround you provided is working great so thanks again for that :)

Comment: FWIW it was the engine that was at fault. Changing it to `ENGINE=InnoDB` solved it for me

Comment: @Carty: I'm pleased that you were able to find an answer to your question... looking at existing answers on other questions, before asking another question.

Comment: @spencer7593 I always exhaust all my options before asking a new question. Most things are already answered so I try my best using those solutions. Then, if all else fails, I will ask away.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see much use in a foreign key constraint between two columns that are both defined with "auto_increment". In your example, you could easily create several rows in table "foo" (without a counterpart in "foo2"), and from then onwards you could not control whether "id" values in both tables match.

I admit I didn't check the documentation, but it would not surprise me if MySQL silently ignored a foreign key constraint for an auto-generated column.

IMNSHO, your table "foo2" should use "id" values which are set explicitly and reference specific rows in "foo", because then it would make sense that deleting such "foo" rows should cascade onto "foo2".

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This was just a simple example, I tried it with variations on the id column, including without the auto_increment, with the same results.

Comment: But actually that was an error on my part while typing up my question, I did try with auto_increment, but the "main" way I did it was without --good call